# Applying dynamic formatting in Excel on multiple tables on the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, formatting

I use an Excel document to track cryptocurrencies and I have multiple tables on the same sheet. I'm looking for the VBA code that would format the cells based on the input in another cell.

Currently I'm formatting based on another cell with the below code. Example of what I'm trying to achieve: http://prntscr.com/p3sof8

Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            If .Column = 1 Then
                If .Value <> "BTC" Then
                    .Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = "0.00000000" & """ " & .Value & """"
                Else
                    .Offset(, 1).NumberFormat = """" & ChrW(&HE3F) & """" & "0.00000000"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

This works perfectly for one sheet.

What I'm looking for is to use this kind of a code for multiple tables on the same sheet, that have different offsets, "defining" columns etc.

For example, on Table1, the currency is inputed in column A, and formatted cell is in column B. On Table2, the input column is C and results are in E and F, etc.

Can the above code be altered in a way that I could use it for different tables on a single sheet?

Thank you very much for your insights!

Comment: Are your tables formatted as actual Tables (Listobjects) ?

Comment: Yes, I think they are, as I refer in other functions to a named table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's tied to tables and you can't have duplicate table names you can place this in ThisWorkbook and start like this:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
```

... and it will work on every sheet.

..or like this in specific sheet if it's only needed in one sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
```

..then:

```
    Dim lObj As ListObject, cl As Long, ofs As Long, rsz As Long, fc As Long
    With Target
        If .Count = 1 Then
            Set lObj = .ListObject
            If Not lObj Is Nothing Then
                fc = lObj.Range.Cells(1).Column - 1
                Select Case lObj
                    Case "Table1"
                        cl = 1 + fc 'Starting column
                        ofs = 1 'Offset
                        rsz = 1 'Resize(number of columns)
                    Case "Table2"
                        cl = 3 + fc 'Starting column
                        ofs = 2 'Offset
                        rsz = 2 'Resize(number of columns)
                    'Case "Table3"
                    '    cl = 4 + fc 'Starting column
                    '    ofs = 7 'Offset
                    '    rsz = 1 'Resize(number of columns)
                End Select

                If .Column = cl Then

                    Select Case .Value
                        Case "BTC"
                            .Offset(, ofs).Resize(, rsz).NumberFormat = """" & ChrW(&HE3F) & """" & "0.00000000"
                        Case "EUR"
                            .Offset(, ofs).Resize(, rsz).NumberFormat = "0.00" & """" & ChrW(8364) & """"
                        Case Else
                            .Offset(, ofs).Resize(, rsz).NumberFormat = "0.00000000" & """ " & .Value & """"
                    End Select
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you - it works! But at the same time as I'm getting the right result I'm also getting an error: http://prntscr.com/paakz7

Comment: I'd also like to add another currency down the currency expression that has special attributes - we have BTC and "else". I'd like to add EUR - so if EUR is inputed in a column, the result is 0,00 €. I've tried to add it to IF argument, with no luck. Thank you!

Comment: @Kgx Added a condition that excludes interaction with non-listobjects that should prevent some errors and also alternatives for placement of the code. Please accept if this answers your question.

Comment: Ok, cool - the answer is accepted - it all works amazing. Thank you again for all your help!